# How to upload a css style like this link "https://example.com/index.php?aiJo82uwn=index.css" something like that

Tags: html, css

Newbie here.. I just want know how to attach a css file like this https://example.com/index.php?aiJo82uwn=index.css . Most of the companies like Facebook, Google, Instagram etc. are using that mehod I just wanna ask how to do that one ? Is it something like GET requests or Query Strings ??

Comment: The index.php file, takes responsibility to return the index.css file or create the CSS file on the fly, depending on certain attributes of the user logged in or kind of device he's using to interact with the website.

Comment: How to return a file in PHP ??

Comment: You just echo the contents of the file with appropriate headers

Answer (score 0):

Most of the css files are attached in the html head tag like this 
 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">.` 
But I think they get their css-files from a server so it has an url behind the css name. Hope I could help